# Greenfields project using Sails.js and NodeBB - Is Passport suitable for providing single-sign on?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js, nodebb

I'm an experienced `Ruby` (`Sinatra`, `Event Machine`, `Warden`, etc) developer and have decided to teach myself `Node.js`

I've written enough `Node` now to feel very comfortable with it, and now I'm feeling a bit more ambitious. I would like to wire a simple `Sails.js` app and a forum built with `NodeBB` together such that my users can sign into one and be automatically signed in to the other.

I'd like those users to have `role-based authentication` for access to various parts of the `Sails` app and also of the forum, so they'd need to share a common `RBAC` model.

Is `Passport` suitable for this? And if so, do you have any links to examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To persist sessions across requests, `Passport` relies on `Connect`, which in turn relies on encrypted cookies containing a connect session id. To use the same sessions across multiple applications, you will need to synchronize your `Express` / `Connect` cookie parser and synchronize or share your sessions and user models. You would need to use an external session store (like Redis or Mongo) and probably separate your user database from the individual application databases. Additionally, you would need to copy and paste the cookie parser secret into each application.

It's not really the best approach, though. The maker of `Passport` also published an [open-source OAuth2 Server](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize), which you can use (in combination with `Passport`'s OAuth 2 authentication support) to provide authentication for all the applications you want to tie together. This is a much more robust and scalable solution to your problem, as you won't have to worry about synchronizing secrets and sharing databases. Additionally, it would allow you to write any kind of application you want (not necessarily in node) and still implement shared single sign on.

(If that still sounds like more effort than it's worth, you can always just use an external identity provider. Google-account based OpenID requires no setup, integrates seamlessly with `Passport`, and lets Google do all the work.)

Comment: Thanks that's certainly given me some leads to go on.